# Setting up CI/CD pipeline on Gitlab (Windows, yml)

Tags: node.js, gitlab, continuous-integration

I am trying to set-up CI/CD pipeline for my electron application on gitlab. The gitlab-runner was setup on a windows machine and is currently online. In the codebase, the yml file is placed in the root folder. The pipeline starts, there is a connection between runner and gitlab.
I'm facing an issue in finding the npm. Although nodejs and npm are installed in C:\Program Files\nodejs, still I am getting the error on shell executor.

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
   stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - BuildServerTag
  before_script:
    - SET PATH=$c/PROGRA~1/nodejs/
  script:
    - echo "Hello World"
    - npm -v
```

Error:
npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I have tried the following:

1. Set C:\Program Files\nodejs as system environment variable on runner.
2. use SET Path in yml file
3. use complete path to npm in yml file

Comment: Does the gitlab-runner user have permissions to the nodejs executable? By default it will run with a service user account and you may need to grant permissions to that user. This is almost always the issue when you can run something locally but hit errors when running it from CI/CD.

Comment: It has all the permissions. The source code from gitlab is downloaded to the node/runner but can't find npm

Comment: You're on the right track. You need to have it on PATH. I just don't think your syntax is quite correct. What shell are you using in the executor? Powershell or cmd or bash? You'll also want to make sure you're preserving existing PATH values (ie just prepend the entry into PATH, don't override PATH completely). Alternatively, edit the SYSTEM (not user) environment variables on the host to include this entry in PATH (restart the system after this change to ensure it takes effect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using powershell, you can change PATH like this:

```
script:
  # check that the files are actually there
  - dir "C:\Program Files\nodejs"
  # append nodejs onto PATH
  - '$env:Path += ";C:\Program Files\nodejs"'
```

Also ensure that your NodeJS binary files are *actually* in `C:\Program Files\nodejs` (IIRC this is the default if you use the official installer) not some subdirectory like `nodejs\bin` which may be the case if you use a third-party tool for installing nodejs.

The output of `dir C:\Program Files\nodejs` in your job should yield something like:

```
    Directory: C:\Program Files\nodejs


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----          6/5/2021   9:10 PM                node_modules
-a----         5/11/2021   5:44 PM           3032 install_tools.bat
-a----         5/11/2021   6:03 PM       56742536 node.exe
-a----         4/27/2020   8:13 PM            702 nodevars.bat
-a----         4/27/2020   8:13 PM           8997 node_etw_provider.man
-a----         5/11/2021   5:44 PM            930 npm
-a----         5/11/2021   5:44 PM            483 npm.cmd
-a----         5/11/2021   5:44 PM            922 npx
-a----         5/11/2021   5:44 PM            539 npx.cmd
```

You'll also need to check your `PathExt` variable includes `.exe` (to execute `node`) and `.cmd` to execute (to execute `npm`). This is the case by default, so no action should be needed if you've not modified `PathExt`.

Alternatively, you can use the full path to `npm` INCLUDING the `.cmd` extension:

```
script:
  - 'C:\Progra~1\nodejs\npm.cmd -v'
```

Comment: with this  'C:\Progra~1\nodejs\npm.cmd -v' I'm able to reach npm. Thanks